# (HTML & CSS) How to perform an action when the user presses "Enter"

Tags: html, css, input, google-chrome-extension

*I was wondering how to make it so the user can type in some text and press enter to perform an action.  I've found tutorials on how to do this however I want to only use HTML and CSS.*

*Edit: A user by the name ScottieG informed me that I cannot do this without HTML and CSS alone.  I didn't make this clear but I CAN use Javascript but I just can't use certain functions such as  , eval() , or new Function.  You can use this link to learn more: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy *

```css
input[name="newtask"] {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 418px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task"><br>
```

Comment: This is not possible with HTML and CSS alone. HTML is your document structure,  and CSS is styles and formatting. You need JS or PHP to add behaviours such as POST.

Comment: "but I just can't use certain functions such as , eval()"  Why would you?  Why even go there?  Can you explain in more detail what it is you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can put input inside a form and have a submit button. By default in a form on pressing enter Submit action is performed.

`<form action="/action">
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task"><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Your informer scottie G is correct because html and css languages are only used for designing and developing webpages and talking about including form button in the code, yes you can perform a submit but that submit can't perform any action or we can say that you will not get the information that has been inputted by the other user in the form unless you create a php page to transfer the information from your form to a database. If you want to learn back-end than go for the language PHP, and start it from basic because front-end i.e is HTML and CSS is only the basic thing or 5% of whole web development. Their is also predefined PHP codes available in the internet for taking input from your form but i prefer to learn PHP in the long run. It will be beneficial for your web development part.